# Using ryanfait.com custom form elements with .net autopostback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I am using ryanfait.com custom form elements to change the appearance of my dropdown lists in my .net web application.  Everything works fine except for .net postbacks on dropdown lists.  Having looked at the javascript code for custom work elements I have noticed that the onchange event is overwritten:

```
    if(!inputs[a].getAttribute("disabled")) {
    inputs[a].onchange = Custom.choose;
    } else {
    inputs[a].previousSibling.className = inputs[a].previousSibling.className += " disabled";
    }
```

If I comment out the above code the autopostback works but for other dropdownlists which do not require an autopostback the input value now does not change.  Is there a way I can get this working for both scenarios?  On ryanfait.com he says:

onChange and other JavaScript events
This script utilizes JavaScript's onChange and other events. Because these events can only be used once, if you want to add more functions to an event, you will need to call them from inside my script.

But I can't work out if I can somehow trigger the autopostback event?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is that supposed to be "Accessing"?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way do this is to add a a standard asp:dropdownlist with autopostback, preview your page and then view source, find the list in the HTML source and copy the onChange property. this is what you need to call client side to post the page back.

eg.

```
onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ddlHolidayType\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)"
```